# Unable to store multiline string (private ssh key) as variable in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to store an `ssh` private key as an `ansible` variable.

It is in an encrypted file and it goes more or less like this

```
my_private_key: |
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----

kd02ke0ke0k20ke0ke40430940943090494
[...]

Xekrfmfimimfimfeimiefmim4304309430943==

-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

However, `ansible` execution fails as follows:

```
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  could not find expected ':'

The error appears to be in '/Users/pantelis/path/to/my/encrypted/file': line 6, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
```

Is there something wrong about the way I am storing this multiline variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The block value needs to be indented farther than the key.

```
my_private_key: |
  -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
  kd02ke0ke0k20ke0ke40430940943090494
  Xekrfmfimimfimfeimiefmim4304309430943==
  -----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```